# How to Correctly Set up Dual Boot windows 7 and ubuntu on 120Gb SSD drive with UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

For as long as i have had my Alienware M17xr4 Laptop i've been trying to set up dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 in UEFI mode..        I have a 120 SSD Drive partitioned to 80GB for the Windows 7, 24GB for Ubuntu and a 7GB Partition for ubuntu swap space.     When installing ubuntu there is no option to install next to windows 7.    So i choose the do something else option.   Once the partitioning screen loads up i make a 600mb EFI boot, I choose the 24GB for root partition and the 7GB partition for swap.      Once Installed reboot and no Grub or any kind of option to dual boot.   it's just normal boot up into windows.     even if i press the f12 while booting and choose to boot from the hard drive i installed ubuntu on it says no operating system detected or gives me an error of some sort.    I've tried this every way possible.   Couple months ago i had it working but it was set up to where i had to go into the Bios and change it from UEFI to Legacy and back every time i would want to switch from windows to Ubuntu.    I've tried BCD easy boot although i'm not sure if correctly set it up the time i tried it.   And I've also Tried WUBI.   No sucess.   I'm booting from Usb.     Can anyone shed some light.   Would be highly appreciated,  i have been wanting to get this dual boot properly set up for a while now it's just frustrating as im sure u understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to bridge 2 generations: you want to install the latest and greatest Ford Mustang 2015 engine in the original 1964 Convertible body.  (Ubuntu in UEFI mode and Windows in MBR mode) which then means: changing the BIOS every time you want to switch!

So sometimes you have to tell people: [Don't do it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saUVi5r_-ZU)

UEFI was (and up to a certain point: still is) just a scheme to allow computer vendors to *lock out* OSes like Linux (and companies who re-program the BIOS of their machines still can!) so there is *no need* to run in UEFI mode!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: im just going to have to switch the bios every time i want to switch OS? or can they both be ran side by side in legacy?

Comment: *that* is the best solution for you!